# Why is the compiler requiring instance variable access over property access in class extension?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The compiler in Xcode requires for me to use the instance variable name for a property declared in a class extension

```
@interface Person ()
@property NSString *bar
@end

@implementation Person 
 -(void) foo {
     NSString *foo = _bar; // underscore required here
 }
@end
```

In the code example above why can I not access bar without the underscore?

Comment: because you haven't `synthesized` it yet.

Comment: I was under the impression properties are synthesized automatically by the compiler as they are when declared in the interface of the .h. Is this incorrect? @Rahul

Comment: Also `_bar` is a ivar and it got created when you declared with `@property`. but synthesize does this mapping `@synthesize undoManager=_undoManager`

Comment: bar is a property, not an instance variable. If you want access to it use: self.bar. And yes there are auto synthesized, that means than compiler create for you an instance variable called _bar for store your property. Yes you can access to it directly.

Comment: @Rahul's initial comment is incorrect. @Onik's comment is correct. The property in this case was auto synthesized and can be accessed directly with `_bar` or through the property getter as `self.bar`.

Comment: I removed it.@Dima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `bar` as `self.bar` and it's more preferred than `_bar`. `_bar` is available for legacy code.

Looks like you came to Objective-C from Swift where the compiler adds `self.` for you automatically.

Comment: How come the properties declared in the .h interface don't need self and Xcode doesn't force the instance variable access? Does it have to do with the property in a class extension?

Comment: Correction: Accessing the ivar directly is not for legacy code, and indeed both `self.bar` and `_bar` have been valid since `@property` has existed. Sometimes, you may want to access the underlying variable directly without going through the getter or setter function called by `self.bar`

Comment: @lostAtSeaJoshua the difference is accessing the variable directly or accessing it through the getter or setter method. Both are valid in Objective-C. In Swift, this distinction no longer exists.

Comment: @Dima, you shouldn't use ivars directly. Accessing ivars directly isn't safe in multithreading application. That's why Swift doesn't allows that.

Comment: @Dima thank you for the clarification! It's easy to spot a Swift to Objective-C programmer haha.

Comment: Properties can be declared atomic, doesn't that add thread safety? @JoshCaswell

Comment: It synchronizes the getter and setter with respect to each other, but not to anything else, @lostAtSeaJoshua. It's one component of safety. There's no higher-level ordering of the sets and gets. If thread A and thread B both set a value while thread C does a get, C will receive one or the other, rather than a corrupted combination of the two, but _which_ is indeterminate.

Comment: You are correct @rob, doing some research atomic makes a property more resistant to threading errors.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, @rmaddy actually even non-atomic properties are little threadsafer than direct access to ivars. That's why you can't access ivars in Swift directly: when you use `self.` or not, every time accessors will be called. I can't explain in limited space of stackoverflow comments. Please just believe me.